# Call to a member function prepare() on null OOP

Tags: php, oop

Having trouble understanding classes and inheritance:

core.php:

```
$servername = "****";
$database = "****";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

class Database {

  protected $pdo;

  public function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }
}

class User extends Database {

  private $ip;
  private $sessionId;

  public function __construct($ip, $sessionId) {
    $this->ip = $ip;
    $this->sessionId = $sessionId;
  }
  public function getSessionInfo () {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(".."); <-- error here
    ....
  }
}
```

When calling:

```
require_once 'api/core.php';
$database = new Database($pdo);
$user = new User($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SESSION['info']['id']);
```

Comment: How can you get an error if you don't even call `getSessionInfo`. I think you don't show us everything here. Also `$database` and `$user` are two different objects, which don't have anything to do with each other!

Comment: You need to assign Database object to user

Comment: you need to call parent construct to access the variable in construct of parent .

Comment: ah woops, I do that just below `$sessionInfo = $user->getSessionInfo();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this contest $database, and $user variables are not related to each other:

```
require_once 'api/core.php';
$database = new Database($pdo);
$user = new User($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SESSION['info']['id']);
```

Thus, calling prepare() on $user won't work.

You need a mechanism, at least like this , although not a good practice to assign Database to a User:

```
$user->setDatabase($database);
```

Instead create a static Database object, initiate it before User initiation, and call it statically within User object, or any other object, make it available for all objects.

A quick fix would look like this, where User doesn't extend Database, because it's wrong. *User* is not a *Database*.

```
$database = new Database();
$user = new User();
$user->setDatabase($database); //sets $db variable inside User

//User.php
namespace MyApp;

class User{
    private Database $db;

    public function setDatabase($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function doSomething(){
         $this->db->getPdo()->prepare('..');
    }
}

//Database.php
namespace MyApp;

class Database{

    private $pdo; //returns PDO object

    function __construct(){

         //create pdo connection
         $this->pdo = ..
    }

    function getPdo(){
         return $this->pdo;
    }

}
```

Database should be injected to objects or used by objects, you shouldn't be extending Database just to have it. If you want to do it properly, in an object-oriented way.

Remember PHP doesn't allow multiple inheritances by extend. Tomorrow, you might want to have a Person class that every User will extend, but since you did it wrong in the beginning, and wasting precious `extend` on Database, it won't be possible. And by not having a control of how many database instances you have created, you will run into issues. You need to know for sure that you have only a single connection object for one database, if of course the opposite is a must - which in your case I doubt.

Of course this will change if you have multiple database requirements, and more sophisticated app structure.

Comment: `Instead create a static Database object, initiate it before User initiation, and call it statically within User object, or any other object, make it available for all objects` How would I do that?

Comment: There are many ways. Your question was why it doesn't work I showed you why. If you need to learn how, accept this question, and start a new one please. Because your code needs a complete redesign.

Comment: What exactly do I put in the setDatabase function? I'm confused

Comment: Never mind I saw your edit, damn it seems to be overcomplicating things from standard procedural :S

Comment: Standart procedural and OOP two very very different paradigms. OOP is its own style, its not overcomplicating, in the long run you benefit. PHP is becoming more and more an OO language. Of course if you are preparing a one file, one time script, you might as well go procedural. Ive built many sophisticated large projects back in the days, procedural style)). OOP is a style, you either choose it or not, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because User Instance has pdo empty. try this code

```
$servername = "****";
$database = "****";
$username = "****";
$password = "****";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

class Database {

  protected $pdo;

  public function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }
}

class User extends Database {

  private $ip;
  private $sessionId;

  public function __construct($pdo, $ip, $sessionId) {\
    parent::__construct($pdo)
    $this->ip = $ip;
    $this->sessionId = $sessionId;
  }
  public function getSessionInfo () {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("..");
    ....
  }
}
```

then

```
require_once 'api/core.php';
$user = new User($pdo, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_SESSION['info']['id']);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: no please,  don't do that. Don't extend Database on User, it's just wrong, and for other reasons too. It is a quick hack, but will hurt in long run.

Comment: @MuhammedM. so extends are not used that way?

Comment: definetely not in that way. Database should be injected to objects or used by objects, you shouldn't be extending Database just to have it. If you want to do it properly, in an object-oriented way.